# Defining type string | undefined inside an Type of array of strings

Tags: typescript, types

I have custom types which is the following:

```
hero?: string
power?: string
```

I want to add those type into an array, which is part of another type

```
type Superheroes = {
character: string[] | []
villains: number | null
city: string

}
```

When I try to use the type (see below) I get the following error `Typescript: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'`

```
return {
character: [hero, power],
villains: 2 || null,
city: 'new york' || null
}
```

What is the correct way to define `hero` and `power` types inside the character array?

Comment: Could you make an edit in the example please tsplay.dev/mL9MKW ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it assignable you should define your `Superheroes` type like that:

```typescript
type Superheroes = {
  character: (string | undefined)[]
  villains: number | null
  city: string
}
```

or if there are always no more than two elements in `character` array:

```typescript
type Superheroes = {
  character: [string?, string?]
  villains: number | null
  city: string
}
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBzlzN)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type to :

```
city: string || null
```

or change the assign of the `city` attribute to :

```
city: 'new york'
```

without the array or null.

Comment: The issue is with the `hero` and `power` types inside the `character` array. The `city` being an array was a typo which is now fixed

Comment: oh ok. I see that you add question mark to `hero?: string` and `power?: string` without initialization and that could be `undefined`, I think you can try initialization `hero` and `power` like this: `hero?: string = '';
power?: string = '';` to avoid the error.